# How to solve circular dependency in Scala?

Tags: scala, design-patterns

I faced a problem with circular dependency in my Scala app.
To give you more context, I have the structure below:

`trait CService`

`trait PMService extends CService`

`trait BTService extends CService with PMService`

In `BTService` I need some functionality from `CService` and in `PMService` also. I can see that there is a redundant dependency here (`CService`) but how can I avoid it?

Comment: `PMService` is a `CService`, so `BTService` can `extends PMService` only.

Comment: There's no circular dependency here. That would be e.g. `trait PMService extends CService` and `trait CService extends PMService`.

Comment: Why couldn’t you only extends CServices with PMServices and PMServices with BTServices. You will get functionality of both in BTServices

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no circular dependency, but you are unnecessarily extending CServices and PMServices to BTServices. You can do it like this.

```
trait CServices
trait PMServices extends CServices
trait BTServices extends PMServices
```

That way you will be able to use all the functionality of PMServices and CServices.